# Find area of parallelogram with matrix vertices

Tags: matrices

Let ${v} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$ and ${w} = \begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}$. Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices ${0}$, ${v}$, ${w}$, and $v + {w}$.

What is the best way to start this?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Area of the parallelogram with the vectors $u$ and $v$ as sides is $A = |u \times v|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use determinant formula - | u x w |.

```
det(5,-3) x det(11,-2) 

=(5 x -2) - (11 x -3)

=23
```

P.S. - I am sorry I am new to Maths SE so doesn't know how to edit this stuff. But , I try to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply something about determinants.

Alternatively, find the fourth vertex of the parallelogram and then do everything from scratch.   Maybe I could post something about working "from scratch" if I were incited enough.

Answer (score 0):

That question is begging to be answered with determinants. The area of the parallelogram formed by your vectors $v$ and $w$ is:

$$A = \left|\det \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 11 \\ -3 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \right| = 23$$

Here's an image I stole from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it with determinants as the other answers suggest, but would rather like a more classical geometrical approach, the area of the parallelogram is twice the area of the triangle $\triangle 0vw$. And that triangle's area can be found using [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).